# Why do new variable names need to be on the left of the equals (=)?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I am curious as to why a certain format produces an error while the other doesn't.

Code that works:

```
name = input().split()

if len(name) == 3:
  first_name, middle_name, last_name = name
  print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.{middle_name[0]}.')

elif len(name) == 2:
  first_name, last_name = name
  print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.')
```

Code that does not work:

```
name = input().split()

if len(name) == 3:
  name= first_name, middle_name, last_name
  print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.{middle_name[0]}.')

elif len(name) == 2:
  name = first_name, last_name
  print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.')
```

The only difference in these two are in lines 4 and 8 where the `name =` ends up being. I always put the variable on the left so i'm lost as to why this needs to be on the right.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a decent question, but the title doesn't describe the problem at all. Please [edit] to put a clearer title, like for example, "Why do new variable names need to be on the left of the equals (=)?" For tips, see [ask].

Comment: Lines 2 and 6 are blank... you mean 4 and 8, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those say two entirely different things. The second one takes three objects (first_name, middle_name, last_name), then builds them into a tuple, and assigns that to `name`. That's clearly not what you want, since those three names do not exist. Your first example takes the three parts of the variable `name` (which does exist), and unpacks them into those three objects. Your second sample is just not the way you write an assignment statement. An assignment takes what's on the RIGHT, and assigns it into what's on the LEFT.

After all, you write:

```
num = 3
```

and not

```
3 = num
```

right?

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to programming or you're more familiar with math notation, the concept of `=` might be confusing, because it's not actually an *equivalence*, it's more like *naming*. When you write a statement of the form `name = value`, like for example `foo = 0`, that means, "take the value `0` and store it under the name `foo`". You can think of `name` as a label if that helps your understanding.

In your case, you want to take the strings from the list `name` and store them under the labels `first_name`, possibly `middle_name`, and `last_name`, respectively. To demonstrate, let's say `name` is `['John', 'Doe']`. That means you want to store `'John'` under `first_name` and `'Doe'` under `last_name`. So how you do that is to write,

```
first_name, last_name = name
```

If we substitute `name` with the value that *it* references, it becomes clearer:

```
first_name, last_name = ['John', 'Doe']
```

Then Python *unpacks* the list and this becomes equivalent to:

```
first_name = 'John'
last_name = 'Doe'
```

---

For reference, the exact semantics are explained in The Python Language Reference: [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). (Syntactically, `target_list` has multiple `targets`, all of which are `identifier`s, and the RHS is a `starred_expression` which boils down to `primary` -> `atom` -> `identifier`.)